# Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: react-native

I am getting an below error. I can see that I have to return array instead of object. But I am really not sure how to fix it.

> Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a
> collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using
> createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method
> of `View`.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {timeElapsed: null};
  }

startStopButton(){
    return <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="gray" onPress={this.handleStartPress.bind(this)}>
        <Text>Start</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
  }

handleStartPress(){
      var startTime = new Date();
      



      setInterval(()=>{
        this.setState({timeElapsed: new Date()})
      }, 1000);
  }
render(){
return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={[styles.header]}>
      <View style={[styles.timerContainer, this.borderColor('#ff6666')]}>
        {this.state.timeElapsed}
      </View>
      <View style={[styles.buttonsContainer, this.borderColor('#558000')]}>
        {this.startStopButton()}
        {this.lapButton()}
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
);


}
```

Comment: Can you show your render method?

Comment: You're not showing anything that can help us debug it, the render method would be where I start.

Comment: Hi I have just added render method. Thanks

Comment: what is your `styles` containing?

Comment: I am also getting the same error for https://github.com/kushmpatel/auth_React_Demo this demo. Can you please checkout this project and check it? I am learning react native and seriously have no idea where is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

timeElapsed is an object, React doesn't know how to render this:

```
  <View style={[styles.timerContainer, this.borderColor('#ff6666')]}>
    {this.state.timeElapsed}
  </View>
```

Try changing `this.state.timeElapsed` for a string like for example:

```
  <View style={[styles.timerContainer, this.borderColor('#ff6666')]}>
    {this.state.timeElapsed.toString()}
  </View>
```

Comment: Thanks Emilio for explanation and example. It worked for me. There's one more error I had however I have solved it. But I'm just not sure why it works.

Comment: i install third party plugins minutes-seconds-milliseconds and wrapped up  timeElapsed. `{formatTime(this.state.timeElapsed)}` 
<pre>
`handleStartPress(){
      var startTime = new Date();
      
      setInterval(()=>{
        console.log(this.setState({timeElapsed : new Date()}));
        this.setState({timeElapsed: new Date()})
      }, 30);
  }`  </pre>


Now I am getting my timeElapsed undefined.

Comment: I am also getting the same error for github.com/kushmpatel/auth_React_Demo this demo. Can you please checkout this project and check it? I am learning react native and seriously have no idea where is the problem in my code?

Comment: @KushPatel in your `LoginForm` you have a couple of `<CardSection></CardSection>`. That `CardSection` component renders `props.children` but nothing was passed as children so it will try to render an invalid value. I guess as soon as you remove those CardSections everything should be fine

Comment: @EmilioRodriguez I removed that code `<CardSection></CardSection>`  but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Note note={
 <p>{(new Date(updated_at)).toString()}</p>
} />
```

In this case, Note is my child component and I had passed date as above and it worked for me.

**Output**
[Pass date to React Child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yv6Fd.png)

Answer (score 1):

- Short & simple is that use `JSON.stringify()`
- because `this.state.timeElapsed` is the object. object not able to print in normal standered. Thus we need to render that object in `JSON.stringify()`. It converted into JSON form.
- Try this, It's work for me

```
{JSON.stringify(this.state.timeElapsed)}
```

Comment: `.toString()` is what I tried first based on my own personal foreknowledge. I still got an error. I was disappointed to see the same idea offered here. However, I forgot about `JSON.stringify(...)` and it worked. Thank you!