# Error in map function / Objects are not valid as a React child / React.js

Tags: reactjs, loops

I'm making a application using React.js. I fetch some data using API and I'm trying to show that data in a list. Currently I receive the following error when I tried to iterate through the data.

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {USDUSD, USDEUR, USDCAD, USDAUD}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Exchange

Even though I store the data in array, this error appears.

I checked that there is a similar thread related this error : [Objects are not valid as a React child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604539/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child), but these answer does not help my case.

Here is my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const baseUrl = 'http://apilayer.net/api/historical?'
const API_KEY = 'API_KEY'
const date = '2017-10-22';
const currencies = 'USD,EUR,CAD,AUD';
const format = 1;


export default class Exchange extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        item : []
    };
}

componentDidMount(){
const url = `${baseUrl}${API_KEY}&date=${date}&currencies=${currencies}&format=${format}`
axios.get(url)
     .then(({data}) => {
        this.state.item.push(data.quotes);
        this.setState({
            item: this.state.item
        });
     })
     .catch((err) => {})
 console.log("item" + this.state.item)
 }

render() {
const rate = this.state.item.map((element, index)=>{
   console.log("element" + element)
return <div key={index}>
        <p>{element}</p>
        </div>
 }); 

    return (
        <div>
        <div>Exchange</div>
        <ul>Today's rate
        <li>{ rate }</li>
        </ul>
       </div>
        )
    }
 }
```

Comment: `element` is properly not a string, number or array..

Comment: what does `console.log('element', element)` return ?

Comment: yes, you are right. Mistakenly I pasted it so I edit the code now. Still I receive the same error.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda It returns `element[object Object]`

Comment: Okay yeah so that won't work. You need to use the data from that object to render the items. What data is in the object? In your `componentDidMount`, what is `data.quotes`?

Comment: And your set state doesn't look correct. It should be: `this.setState({ item: this.state.item.concat([data.quotes]) });`

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Data.quotes is `{USDUSD: 1, USDEUR: 0.850499, USDCAD: 1.26377, USDAUD: 1.280799}`

Comment: `console.log("data quotes" + this.state.item)`  in componentDidMount() returns `data quotes[object Object],[object Object]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since each `quote` is an object, you can use **[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** to loop through the object in the `.map()` to display each value.

```js
const baseUrl = 'http://apilayer.net/api/historical?'
const API_KEY = 'API_KEY'
const date = '2017-10-22';
const currencies = 'USD,EUR,CAD,AUD';
const format = 1;
const quotes = {
  USDUSD: 1,
  USDEUR: 0.850499,
  USDCAD: 1.26377,
  USDAUD: 1.280799
};

class Exchange extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      item: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //const url = `${baseUrl}${API_KEY}&date=${date}&currencies=${currencies}&format=${format}`
    //axios.get(url)
    //.then(({data}) => {
    this.setState({
      item: this.state.item.concat([quotes])
    });
    //})
    //.catch((err) => {})
    //console.log("item" + this.state.item)
  }

  render() {
    const rate = this.state.item.map((quotes, index) => {
      return Object.keys(quotes).map(key => {
        return (
            <div key = {key} >
              <p>{quotes[key]}</p>
            </div>
          )
      })
    });

    return ( 
      <div>
        <div>Exchange</div> 
        <ul> 
          Today 's rate
          <li> {rate} </li> 
        </ul>
     < /div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < Exchange / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer with a code snippet. It worked with my project perfectly. I didn't know about `object.key()`.

Comment: Awesome glad you got it working! In the future we'll also have `Object.values(obj)` which will return an array of all the values, pretty sweet!