# Is the way I wrote my Input.js the reason why I have an Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React Child error?

Tags: javascript, react-native, components, expo

I have an error that says : **Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React Child**. The error does not say exactly which component generates it but from the description of the error, it seems to be complaining about cases where objects are rendered instead of a component. I seem to see such behavior in for example my Input.js which renders:

```
const Input = (props, context) => {
  const styles = getStyles(props, context);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {props.label &&
         <Text style={[styles.label].concat([props.error ? styles.error : 
 {}])}>
          {props.label}
         </Text>}

  {props.icon &&
    <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
      {props.icon}
    </View>}

      <TextInput
        editable={props.editable}
        value={props.value}
        onChangeText={props.onChangeText}
        onFocus={props.onFocus}
        style={[styles.input].concat([props.error ? styles.error : []])}
        underlineColorAndroid="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
        autoCorrect={false}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        placeholderTextColor={props.placeholderTextColor}
        secureTextEntry={props.secureTextEntry}
        multiline={props.multiline}
        numberOfLines={props.numberOfLines}
        fontStyle={props.fontStyle}
      />

      {props.error &&
        <Text style={styles.errorMessage}>
          {props.error}
        </Text>}
    </View>
  );
};
```

As one can easily notice, in many cases an object is being rendered so that the child text or view component is rendered only if

```
//props.error is true
// or if props.icon is true
```

How do I rewrite these so that the Invariant violation error does not exist anymore ?

Here is an attached image of the error:
[image]

Comment: try wrapping  `{props.icon}` inside of the View component in a Text component and calling `.toString()` on when you want to render the values; `{props.error.toString() }` and `{props.icon.toString() }` more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604539/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child)

Comment: Can you show me how exactly you would write that in this case ? Because just adding toString() did not solve my problem

Comment: what type of data are icon, error and label?

Comment: The problem is I don ' t know from which line of code or file to look for it. And my application is big. Any idea on that ? If I had introduced a change recently that broke the code then I will have an idea. But no, it was just upgrading the expo client app that  brought out this. I have been stuck on this for more than 5 days. Thanks for your help. Any idea on how to debug this and find out which file or line to look of code ?

Comment: @ztadic91 Icon is a component from react-native-material-ui and error is an object of object literals

Comment: can provide an example for the error object?