# Error: Object are not valid as a react child?

Tags: react-native

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        value: "Edit me!"
    };
    this.handleChangeText = this.handleChangeText.bind(this);


}

handleChangeText(newText) {
    this.setState({
        value: newText
    });
}


render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput style={styles.editText}
                       onChange={this.handleChangeText}/>
            <Text>hello {this.state.value}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

I am new to react native. I am getting error on  hello {this.state.value} line. How can i solve this. Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objects are not valid as a React child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604539/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child)

Comment: @DeclanNnadozie I don't think so. Both errors are same, but the reason here is different.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this?

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(Props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        value: "Edit me!"
      };
  }
  handleChangeText = (newText) => {
      this.setState({
          value: newText
      });
  }
  render() {
      return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.editText}
                onChangeText={this.handleChangeText}
                />
              <Text>hello {this.state.value}</Text>
          </View>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: The explanation should be that you need to use `onChangeText` to receive the text being types. The code in the question mistakenly uses `onChange` which receives the event. Since this is an object instead of a string, you will get that error which if you want an explanation is in the linked duplicate issue. You can get the text value from the event object, but that is unnecessary with `onChangeText`.