# React app with express and axios gives error on rendering the data

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I am new to the front end technologies. My requirement is to make a post call to an external server. I started with creating the react app and used axios to make the call, but I was getting access denied due to CORS. Some posts on stackoverflow mentioned that I would need a proxy server to overcome this. Thus, I added an express part to the project as well. Below is my react and express codes.

React:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
state = { posts: null };

componentDidMount() {
fetch("/posts")
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    return res;
  })
  .then(posts => this.setState({ posts: posts }));
}

render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Users</h1>
    {this.state.posts}
  </div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

Express:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const axios = require("axios");

router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
axios
.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
.then(response => res.json(response.data))
.catch(err => next(err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I load the React app, I get the below error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Response]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Comment: what is the value for this `this.state.posts`. It needs to be valid React child. If not you need to convert them into valid children. Read more [objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-if-you-meant-to-render-a-collection-of-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428879/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-if-you-meant-to-render-a-collection-of-c) and [objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604539/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child). You might be trying to show an object directly which is not possible

Answer (score 0):

The returned response from the axios fetch is an object, with the payload in `data`. So you need to return that:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  fetch("/posts")
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      return res.data;  // <-- res.data instead of res;
    })
    .then(posts => this.setState({ posts: posts }));
}
```

Comment: I tried this. I don't get any error now, but the data is not being rendered on the page. Even on the console, I can see  a response status 200 , but I can't see the response body. Also, i would like to mention one thing that if you go through my route code , you would see that I am actually returning response.data, so I'm not sure why do I need to mention res.data again in my react file.

Comment: ah, I see. Yes, I guess I just don't know what your fetch function does. Because it "fetches" from `/posts/` but your server route is `/`. Could that be part of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code below and it worked fine. Run `npm install --save axios` before. It omits the express.js application, but maybe it will be helpful.

```html
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Axios from 'axios'

const App = () => {

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('React works')
    Axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(res => {
      if (res.status === 200)
        setPosts(res.data)
      else
        console.log(res.status)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  }, [])
 
  const mappedPosts = posts.map(post => <p key={post.id}>{post.title}</p>)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {mappedPosts}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: That would mean that there is something wrong with ComponentDidMount function, because this.state.posts is empty. I also think that You should use `return res.data` instead of `return res` like @Christian Fritz mentioned, since it's a different request. You make one request in your express.js app and use its data property and another request in your react app and also use its data property. Request object alone also contains information about status code, time etc

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work. All i want is to render the data from this link : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts . Can you please take a look at my code and let me know how to do that.

Comment: Wait a sec, I'll edit this post and put there everything you need

Comment: I need to use express as well. It works fine when I dont have express backend, but I need it to work with a backend.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know express.js enough to help You. Maybe something with CORS?

Answer (score 0):

Actually in 2020 we dont need class components, componendDidMount etc more... you can do a clearly refactoring in your code like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getPosts(){
            const { data } = await fetch('/posts');
            setPosts(data);
        }

        getPosts();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="App">
           <h1>Users</h1>
           {posts.map(post => <p>{post}</p>}
        </div>
     );
}
```

Comment: I tried this. I don't get an error now but I don't see the data being rendered on the page.

Comment: console.log your data to see how it's comming, have in mind that the value is only what should be displayed. Exemple: If your post object is somenthing like: `{message: 'trump agains iran'}` so your out is something like: `<p>{post.message}</p>`

Comment: I added a console log before 'setPosts(data)'. Nothing is logged on the console.

Comment: set at the view! Like `<p>{console.log(post)}</p>`

Comment: Still nothing. I can just see a warning on the console 'backend.js:6 ./src/App.js
  Line 7:  'getPosts' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars'. Nothing apart from that.

Comment: OWww I forgot to call, see I will edit the annswer! just call getPost() after creatign the function, inside the useEffect , as edited.

Comment: Now I get : TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: So let's take a look into the destruction  data, inside useEffect remove `const {data} = ... ` and set without curly braces `cosnt data` and try console.log. We are almost there lol

Comment: Now I get : TypeError: posts.map is not a function. I ve updated as : const data = await fetch("/posts");

Comment: Yes, now totally console.log data before getting the error line, see what kind data you have, object or array of objects, show me what you get!

Comment: I have pasted it here : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205840/discussion-between-t-anna-and-fabio-bc-souza

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) Grab your result from `res.data` because fetch returns an object (data, statusText, etc) when it resolves but you're mostly concerned about the `data`

2) Add an empty array to the state `state : { posts : []}` and then iterate over the array in the render method. Ensure you're not rendering an object. E.G `{{post.name}}` instead of just `{{ post}}`